# Can you heat up a pudding mixture with cool whip?

Tags: heat, pudding

I'm making a dessert that needed instant pudding, but I got the cooking one by accident. I added it without realizing. The mixture is the pudding, milk, and cool whip. If I heat it up, will it ruin the cool whip part? Will it be okay? I don't wanna ruin it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Could you share the recipe, or at least let us know what the final product is supposed to be?

Comment: Try it and let us know what happens

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried heating cool whip, but your only option is to try. Instant pudding will set without heating it, but if you don't cook a heat-set pudding mix it will stay runny, so there's 3 possible outcomes:

1. Don't heat it - ruined
2. Heat it and the cool whip goes wrong - ruined
3. Heat it and it works - success

You lose little by trying.